# Javascript: Uncaught ReferenceError: XMLhttpRequest is not defined

Tags: javascript

I moved a file from one server (where it worked) to another and received this error from the console. Is there some library or something that could be missing from the server? It's running IIS 7 on windows server 2008 R2 Standard.

```
<script> 
        var xmlhttp = new XMLhttpRequest();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's `XMLHttpRequest`, note the capital H

Comment: That was it... Is there a reason the other server ignored it? Isn't this browser-controlled?

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg it has nothing whatsoever to do with the server.